# MongoDB equivalent of SQL COUNT GROUP BY

Tags: sql, mongodb, database

Been reading the mongodb aggregation and group docs, however still unclear to me.

Consider the collection with docs:

{
  a : 1,
  b : 0
}

{
  a : 1,
  b : 1
}

{
  a : 2,
  b : 2
}

{
  a : 3,
  b : 3 
}

I want to count the number of documents for each value of a and sort by the count.

In the relational style it would look something like this:

SELECT COUNT(distinct b) AS total 
FROM example_table 
GROUP BY a 
ORDER BY total DESC;

Any suggestions on how to do this in mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first `$group` on `_id:"$a"` with `$sum:{1}` (this is basically your count on distinct a) then `sort` on the sum.

Comment: db.so.aggregate([ {  $group : { _id :'$a', count: { $sum: 1 } } } ],{$sort:{count: -1}})