# How to use aggregation correctly in MongoDB with embbeded documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, grouping

I have a collection with folowing data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5066b716d3112cfc2a5deb"),
    "username" : "admin",
    "password" : "123456",
    "token" : "0123",
    "bots" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "mybot",
            "installations" : [ 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2018-07-19T10:23:51.774Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2018-07-19T10:23:51.774Z")
                }
            ],
            "commands" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "read",
                    "date" : ISODate("2018-07-19T10:23:51.774Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "answer",
                    "date" : ISODate("2018-07-19T10:23:51.774Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "get",
                    "date" : ISODate("2018-07-19T11:55:28.858Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "get",
                    "date" : ISODate("2018-07-19T11:56:47.419Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "get",
                    "date" : ISODate("2018-07-19T11:56:48.499Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "get",
                    "date" : ISODate("2018-07-19T11:56:49.089Z")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b50bbfe3ed35b6f2bde6923"),
    "username" : "user",
    "password" : "123456",
    "token" : "44444",
    "bots" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "anotherBotName",
            "installations" : [ 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2018-07-19T16:27:42.012Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2018-07-19T16:27:42.012Z")
                }
            ],
            "commands" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "update",
                    "date" : ISODate("2018-07-19T16:27:42.012Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "update",
                    "date" : ISODate("2018-07-19T16:27:42.012Z")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to execute SQL-equivalent query

```
SELECT commands.name, COUNT(commands.name), GROUP BY commands.name
```

and get a result like:

```
 [
     {update: 2},
     {get: 4},
     {read: 1},
     {answer: 1}
 ]
```

but when I execute this query in mongo:

```
 .collection(collectionName).aggregate({{'$group': {_id: "$bots.commands.name",count:{$sum:1}}}
 }).toArray(callback)
```

I get such a result:

```
 [
    { 
        _id: [ 
            [ 'test', 'test1' ] 
        ], 
        count: 1 
    },
    { 
         _id: [ 
             [ 'read', 'answer', 'get', 'get', 'get', 'get' ] 
         ],
        count: 1 
    }
 ]
```

I [googled and read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509524/mongodb-equivalent-of-sql-count-group-by) about agregation in MongoDB and still don't get much. It's hard to move from SQL to NoN-SQL database

My questions are:

**Why my query shows not the result I want to see?**

**How to fix it?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have two nested arrays in your schema you should use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) operator twice before you apply your `$group`. After `$unwind` you'll get separate document for each `name`. Try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$bots"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$bots.commands"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$bots.commands.name",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { obj: [ { k: "$_id", v: "$count" } ] },
                    in: { $arrayToObject: "$$obj" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

In the last stage you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) with [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to set `_id` as keys in your final objects.

Outputs:

```
{ "update" : 2 }
{ "get" : 4 }
{ "answer" : 1 }
{ "read" : 1 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain me the process of how my query works so I get such a weird result?

Comment: I don't see any `[ 'test', 'test1' ] ` in your data but you can easily understand it looking at `[ 'read', 'answer', 'get', 'get', 'get', 'get' ] `. So in your aggregation `bots.commands.name` represents a path to a field `name`inside `commands`and `bots`arrays so Mongo has to evaluate it for each document so it takes all the values from that path and that's why you're getting an array under `_id`